# Is it a good practice to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when it is not currently needed?

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have a base class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and I also have a VS snippet, so the codes can be typed easily. I am writing a data class, but now there is no client that needs to wathch this class' property changes, but there is a possibility that in the future there will be. Is there a reason not to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Will this reduce performance, etc.?

Comment: "Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them." - YAGNI - http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html

Comment: @manojlds you should have put that in an answer, I would have voted it up.

Comment: @TimJarvis - I did, deleted and added as comment!

Comment: @louis Why do you need a base class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you
>   just foresee that you need them."

YAGNI - http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is known to be very lightweight and your real concern is not performance issues and such. If all you are worried about is performance issue, you can as well implement it. YAGNI is not (just) about such issues. It says that your code be flexible that you can when you do need something. That flexibility is what you should be looking at.

Comment: elaborate, please? Would appreciate if you can relate the reasons for that principle to my particular case

Comment: put it in when you need it, NOT if you _think_ you might need it

Comment: @LouisRhys - I have added few lines on your performance concerns

Answer (score 0):

Why not mark the relevant properties as `virtual`, thus making it possible to write a subclass that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` at some point in the future? Your base class will remain lightweight this way.